# How to recreate a open slide effect asp.net web form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, css

I want to create something where I have buttons on the left hand side and then one of these buttons are clicked the page for that button will appear in the space on the right, something like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/N0KvL.png

**(Wont let me upload an image so I provided the URL)**

I have tried to look into it over the Internet but I don't know what the effect is called or even how to get different things to appear in the same browser window.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is the page you want to appear is an html page ?

Comment: Use iFrame. More here http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp